# lightweight website similar to Stack Overflow

Tags: web-applications, frameworks

I have been getting help on Stack Overflow over the last 4 days. I am so impressed that I want to create a similar website but lightweight for internal tools in the company where I am working. What would be the easiest way?

Comment: You want to look at sites like www.getsatisfaction.com, etc. This is gonna get closed though cus its not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few open source solutions similar to Stack Overflow

1. [OSQL](http://www.osqa.net/) - based on Django Framework, [source](http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/Downloading+OSQA)
2. [Shapado](http://shapado.com/) - based on Ruby on Rails, [source](http://shapado.com/pages/code)